# How to wrap element if not already wrapped?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a set of content in which some of the `<img>` tags are wrapped within a span tag as `<span class="the-image"><img src.... /></span>` but some images are not yet wrapped. I want to create a regular expression using preg_replace to add this wrapper to all those img tags that doesn't have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enjoy!

```
preg_replace('/(?!\<span\sclass="the-image"\>)(<img[\sA-Z"\-_=\/.\d]*\/\>)(?!\<\/span\>)/i','<span class="the-image"\>$0</span>',$code);
```

Regex Example & Explanation
https://regex101.com/r/cX8iL6/3

**EDIT**

PHP preg_replace example

```
$code = <<< EOT
<span class="the-image"><img src="123" /></span><br />
<img src="1234" /><br />
<span class="the-image"><img src="blah/blah/blah" /></span>
EOT;

$code = preg_replace('/(?!\<span\sclass="the-image"\>)(<img[\sA-Z"\-_=\/.\d]*\/\>)(?!\<\/span\>)/i','<span class="the-image"\>$0</span>',$code);

/* $code will become this

<span class="the-image"><img src="123" /></span><br />
<span class="the-image"><img src="1234" /></span><br />
<span class="the-image"><img src="blah/blah/blah" /></span>

*/
```

**EDIT 2** Changed regex to and PHP to reflect OP desired answer

Comment: are you sure? You still have opening span on 2nd image.

Comment: Yes, this would make it so

`<span ..><img src="..." ... />`

would become

`<span ..><img src="..." ... /></span>`

Comment: The link doesn't do the replace, it just shows how the regex matches

Comment: The target is supposed to be the images that are not yet wrapped. I mean the one that are just img tags.

Comment: Yes, all img tags that do not have the </span> end wrapper will be wrapped with my code.

Comment: I mean the img that doesn't have both opening & closing spans.

Comment: I'm updating my answer to include an example of what the PHP will do, and not just the matching of the regex

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104762/discussion-between-aslamdoctor-and-josh-s).

Comment: Updated to have desired answer